# Using a single regex to search for 2 criteria in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a function

```
def extract_pid(log_line):
    regex = PROBLEM
    result = re.search(regex, log_line)
    if result is None:
        return None
    return "{} ({})".format(result[1], result[2])
```

My intended outcome of this function is to be able to return the pid numbers between [ ] and the corresponding uppercase text, for example;

```
logline = "July 31 07:51:48 mycomputer bad_process[12345]: ERROR Performing package upgrade"
```

From the above string I'd expect the outcome of my function to return *12345 (ERROR)*

I have 2 criteria to meet in this function `\[\d+\]` and `[A-Z]{2,}` If i test each regex individually I get the expected outcome.

My question is, how do I specify both regex in the same line and output them as displayed in the function above, I cannot find anywhere in the documentation a simple "use this for AND" I found "| for or" but I need it to process both regex criteria.

I understand this could be done in 2 functions and joined together but i've been tasked with doing this from a single function.

Comment: `regex = r'^(?=.*?\[\d+])(?=.*?[A-Z]{2})'`

Comment: Wiktor this doesn't get the intended result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two capturing groups:

```
regex = r'(\[\d+\]).*?([A-Z]{2,})'
```

The `.*?` means "put any characters in between, as few as possible". If you can, replace that with `:` (colon space) assuming that's what's always there.

Comment: Thanks, `regex = \[(\d+)\].*?([A-Z]{2,})` got me exactly the result I wanted, I appreciate the explanation.